# Ubuntu 14.10 for Vmware esxi 5.1

Tags: 14.10, vmware

I have searched the questions for anything similar but cannot find anything.

Key Question : Are there any known \ key issues with running Ubuntu 14.10 under ESXi 5.1?

I have created and configured an Ubuntu 14.10 64 bit virtual environment on an ESXi 5.1 platform.

Installatation was smooth, as was the configuration.
The 4 Ubuntu servers all seem to communicate with each other with no issue, and SSH between them works fine.

VMWare have stated that 14.10 is supported on ESXi 5.5 and above.

Comment: To my knowledge there is no compatibility issue except with the VMware tools in that version of ESXi.  However, VMware is likely more qualified to explain what they mean by 'compatible' and 'supported' for their software

Comment: Thanks Thomas - That may explain some minor behavious issues experienced when building new VMs - The /etc/network/interfaces file was reset to original values (not taking nic information from the vApp) and the hostname reset to the template name.  The power up \ down facilities on the vApp seem to work ok, so that level works.

Answer (score 1):

I am running a handful of Ubuntu 14.10 servers and desktops on ESXi 5.5 with no issues.

Comment: Thanks, Any information on 14.10 under 5.1?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Running esxi 5.1 at work with ubuntu servers ranging from 12.04 to 14.10. No issues with any of them. We have vmware tools installed in them and can snapshot revert pause resume without issue. No issues inside ubuntu itself either.